# Exporting multiple shapefiles as vector tiles with PBF schema

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, vector-tiles, pbf

I work in QGIS and I have to export 2000 shapefiles to vector-tiles with PBF schema.

I have one shape with all the geometries in a single layer and I also export them independently within the same folder.

The "write vector tiles XYZ" tool does not allow to iterate over the layer and in the graphic modeler I can't find how to iterate over a folder using this tool.

How can I do this?